# Add permission on Workflow Task

Tags: workflow, asp.net, tasks

I want to add role assignment to a task (programmatically) when this task is created, but in the method invoking, the task is not created yet. (there is no ID and I can't add SPRoleDefinition)

How can I add roles to a new task? I can't find an "event" or something else when a task is created ...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Non programmatical way.
You can use 2010 workflow with *impersonation step* where are permissions commands. Tick off *Require Manage List permissions* and set it to start when item is created.